# Ubuntu snap-windows feature very slow in VirtualBox guest OS

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, snap-windows

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 in VirtualBox 5.0.6. My host OS is Windows 10.

I have Guest Additions installed, 3D acceleration enabled, and a number of other settings tweaked to maximize performance. I've been using this OS in an older version of VirtualBox for several months without issue. It was only with an upgrade to 5.0.6 that this problem arose.

Performance wise, it runs smoothly in every way EXCEPT when I try to snap a window to the side (or top). The blue semi-transparent box (that pops up where the window will be resized to) appears, and then the system freezes for ~5 seconds before completing the action. I've tried restarting Ubuntu, to no avail.

This isn't a crippling issue, but it is an annoying one, especially when I have lots of work to do and the system freezes whenever I try to move windows around. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've noticed this with Gnome on multiple distros inside VMWare VMs. What I've observed is that if I run a VM in fullscreen and turn on "exclusive mode" so my mouse can only interact with the VM, snapping windows works quickly and flawlessly. If I turn these off and put the VM in windowed mode, it is incredibly slow. If there's an analogous option for VirtualBox I recommend using that as a workaround